# How to use BM25 in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, lucene

I have more than 1 million documents to search, and more than 100,000 keywords. Each keyword needs to search 10 most similar documents in the offline way.
So how to use [Okapi BM25](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okapi_BM25) in spark2, thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m not sure if this will help, but I found this implementation of OkapiBM25 as a Spark estimator that could be useful: https://github.com/yu-iskw/spark-ranking-algorithms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/feature/OkapiBM25.scala